# Does glScissor affect stencil and depth buffer operations?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, depth-buffer, stencil

I know `glScissor()` affects `glColorMask()` and `glDepthMask()`, but does it affect the stencil and depth buffers?

For example:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

glScissor(X,Y,W,H);

// Is this color mask set only for the scissor area?
glColorMask(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE);
// Does this stencil function only work within the scissor area?
glstencilfunc(GL_ALWAYS);
// Does the stencil function only work within scissor area?
glstencilop(GL_KEEP,GL_KEEP,GL_KEEP);
// Is this depth  mask set only for the scissor area?
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
// Does this depth function only work within the scissor area?
glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scissor rectangle applies to pixels within the depth and stencil targets, just as it does to color targets. Only pixels within the scissor rectangle will be candidates for writing, so other states controlling reading from or writing to depth/stencil targets are essentially irrelevant - they will never be read or written. For example, the depth write mask (glDepthMask) does not matter for pixels outside the scissor rectangle, because they will never be written.